# Extract from Dictionary having multiple lists

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark, struct

I have a dataframe having dictionary with multiple lists and I would like to create a dataframe by extracting on a certain element 'Student'.

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {"Student":["Grad","School"], "Comments": "Finished Education"} | {"Student":["New"], "Comments": "Started Education", Location : ["USA", "China", "Australia"]} | {"Student": ["Middle", "School"], "ID" : ["1000", "2000"]}} | {"Student": ["Med","School"]} |

Expected output:

| Student |
| --- |
| Grad, School |
| New |
| Middle, School |
| Med, School |

I have tried to read the dataframe into a dictionary, but was unable to retrieve only the 'Student' element from the dictionary.

```
data_dict = {}
df = df.toPandas()
for column in df.columns:
data_dict[column] = df[column].values.tolist()
Student = [data for data in data_dict.values()]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what you have is *not dictionaries and not lists*. When you have a Spark dataframe, what you call a dictionary is a *struct*. And what you call a list is an *array*. Data types can be inspected with `df.printSchema()`.

You can extract the "Student" fields from the structs, then add everything to an `array` in order to finally `explode`.

```py
arr = F.array([F.col(f'{c}.Student') for c in df.columns])
df = df.select(F.explode(arr).alias('Student'))
```

Full example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [((["Grad","School"], "Finished Education"),(['New'], "Started Education", ["USA", "China", "Australia"]),(["Middle", "School"], ["1000", "2000"]),(["Med","School"],))],
    '`1` struct<Student:array<string>,Comments:string>, `2` struct<Student:array<string>,Comments:string,Location:array<string>>, `3` struct<Student:array<string>,ID:array<string>>, `4` struct<Student:array<string>>')

arr = F.array([F.col(f'{c}.Student') for c in df.columns])
df = df.select(F.explode(arr).alias('Student'))
df.show()
# +----------------+
# |         Student|
# +----------------+
# |  [Grad, School]|
# |           [New]|
# |[Middle, School]|
# |   [Med, School]|
# +----------------+
```

Another working option:

```py
to_melt = [f"`{c}`.Student" for c in df.columns]
df = df.selectExpr(f"stack({len(to_melt)}, {','.join(to_melt)}) Student")
```